# How do I add gap in between items in flatlist?

Tags: react-native, flexbox, react-native-flatlist

I want to add some spacing in react native using flatlist, but it seems more difficult than it should be at the moment.

Turns out that react native does not support `gap` property, which makes this very complicated.

I solved the horizontal spacing, by making my item `49.5%` wide which means I have `1%` space horizontally, now how do I do the same for vertical spacing?

Most importantly how do i ensure that both horizontal and vertical "gaps" are **EQUAL.**

```
const renderItem = ({ item }) => (
  <Pressable onPress={() => alert(item.name)} style={{
        aspectRatio: 1,
    width: "49.5%",
    position: "relative",
  }}>
    <Image
      style={{
        width: "100%",
        height: "100%"
      }}
      source={{
        uri: item.url,
      }}
    />
    <View
      style={{
        position: "absolute",
        zIndex: 3,
        bottom: 0,
        paddingHorizontal: 2,
        paddingVertical: 8,
        flexDirection: "row",
        // justifyContent: "center",
        alignItems: "center",
      }}
    >
      <Text style={{ color: "white", fontSize: 16 }}>{item.name}</Text>
    </View>
  </Pressable>
);

export default function App() {
  return       <FlatList
        numColumns={2}
        data={people}
        renderItem={renderItem}
        columnWrapperStyle={{
          justifyContent: "space-between"
        }}       
      />
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 27, accepted):

### Update

As [Antonio Jaime stated in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77489226/13419373), since RN 0.71 released in January 2023 there is a more clever and straightforward way to do it: `gap` in `contentContainerStyle` and `columnWrapperStyle`. Please check it out.

### Previous Answer

You could use the `ItemSeparatorComponent` property of the `FlatList` component to make the vertical gap. This property is a component rendered in between each `FlatList` item, but not at the top, bottom, right or left. You can read more about it on the [documentation](https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist#itemseparatorcomponent).

Change the `FlatList` to this:

```js
<FlatList
  numColumns={2}
  data={people}
  renderItem={renderItem}
  ItemSeparatorComponent={() => <View style={{height: 20}} />}
  /* that is not necessary anymore
columnWrapperStyle={{
    justifyContent: "space-between"
  }} */      
/>
```

In order for the horizontal space to be given the same size as the vertical space, you can move one column away from the other using `padding`:

- The items on the left have a `paddingRight` of half the size of the vertical space.
- The ones on the right get `paddingLeft` instead of `paddingRight`.

Here's the code:

```js
const renderItem = ({ item, index }: Props) => (
  <View
    style={[
      {
        aspectRatio: 1,
        flexGrow: 1,
        width: "50%",
        position: "relative",
      },
      index % 2 === 0
      ? {
        paddingRight: 10,
      } : {
        paddingLeft: 10
      }
    ]}
  >
    <Pressable
      onPress={() => alert(item.name)}
    >
```

Some points:

- A parent `View` component was created because if the Pressable had the `padding` property, the vertical gap would be pressable too.
- Don't forget to set `width: '50%'` because this makes the images took half the screen's width.
- Both sides should receive the same padding value because this is important to make the gap centered.
- You should use `padding` instead of `margin` because the `width` still is `50%`, so margin would push the elements beyond the right edge of the screen. If you use a greater value like `40` instead of `10` and `margin` instead of `padding` you can see the problem.

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SMo7D.png) was the visual result.

P.S.: I ran your app in my machine with some URL images I got on Unsplash and it worked: the vertical gap was created by the ItemSeparatorComponent.

P.S. 2: I made some changes to the code and now both horizontal and vertical gaps are equal sized. [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SMo7D.png) was the result. In addition, I changed my answer.

Comment: ItemSeparatorComponent does the opposite it renders component at the bottom, are you sure it worked for you?

Comment: Yes, it did. My answer was based on a previous app I worked on, which I used the `ItemSeparatorComponent` to create a divider in between the items in a list. But, I've just run your app here in my emulator and it worked. I'll add a print of it and some code on my original answer.

Comment: sorry, my bad for not mentioning this in original question, yes this prop works, but what I really need is the equal sized gaps, so how do I determine the height for ItemSeparatorComponent that matches horizontal spacing?

Comment: So you want equal sized gaps... I looked up the internet here and tried to discover if there is any FlatList properties that could help, but I found nothing. I tried the hard way: CSS. It worked. If you aask me, the result code was ugly, but it worked. I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 14):

If you're on RN >=0.71 and you want more control over the spacing between columns and items, you can also use the `gap` styling property on [`contentContainerStyle`](https://reactnative.dev/docs/scrollview#contentcontainerstyle) and [`columnWrapperStyle`](https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist#columnwrapperstyle) like so:

```
<FlatList
  // 
  contentContainerStyle={{ gap: GAP_BETWEEN_ROWS }}
  columnWrapperStyle={{ gap: GAP_BETWEEN_COLUMNS }}
  numColumns={2}
  // 
  data={data}
  renderItem={renderItem}
/>
```

Answer (score 7):

The `ItemSeparatorComponent` takes care of the space `between rows` but not between columns. Since we have a two column `FlatList`, we can create the same space as provided by the `ItemSeparatorComponent` between two columns by adding it as a `marginRight` to all the elements that have an `odd index`.

```js
<FlatList
   numColumns={2}
   data={people}
   ItemSeparatorComponent={() => <View style={{height: 10}} />}
   renderItem={({index, item}) =>  (
        <Pressable onPress={() => alert(item.name)} style={{
             aspectRatio: 1,
             width: "49.5%",
             marginRight: index % 2 !== 0 ? 0 : 10,             
             position: "relative",
        }}>
            ...

         </Pressable>})
/>
```

The key part is the `marginRight: index % 2 !== 0 ? 0 : 10` for the parent view of each item in the render function.

Comment: it's actually better to not use separator because it renders fewer views which can have practical performance implications

Answer (score 3):

Simple solution for me was to just added margin around each item and negative margin around container.

Comment: I've seen negative margin break on specific android devices I would stay away from it

Answer (score 2):

A bit late to the party but currently a simple `gap` is working for me:

```
<FlatList contentContainerStyle={{ gap: 16 }} />
```

Comment: Thank you for your interest in contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This question already has quite a few answers—including one that has been extensively validated by the community. Are you certain your approach hasn’t been given previously? **If so, it would be useful to explain how your approach is different, under what circumstances your approach might be preferred, and/or why you think the previous answers aren’t sufficient.** Can you kindly [edit] your answer to offer an explanation?

Comment: How had no one before you given this answer? In my opinion, adding components between list items to create space or using borders to give the illusion of space is bad technique.

Comment: Antonio Jaime has had. As he stated, if you are on RN >=0.71, this is a possible solution. At the moment the most voted answer was published, 0.71 didn't even exist yet. A 0.71 stable was released in January 2023 and the answer was published in August 2022.

Answer (score 0):

to add gap between items in a Flatlist, the best way to do it, is to add columnWrapperStyle prop and passing in justifyContent: 'space-between. so the space between two or more items horizontally, vertically you can just use marginBottom on the items.
or if you want to use an illusion of spacing, you can use a white border around item items, that will make it look like there is spacing between them.

hope this helps

```
<FlatList columnWrapperStyle={{ justifyContent: 'space-between' }} />
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).